# Cant upload file larger than 40MB (ng-file-upload)

Tags: amazon-s3, ng-file-upload

I am trying to upload a file larger than 40MB but it fails and i get below error:

```
<Error> <Code>EntityTooLarge</Code> <Message>Your proposed upload exceeds the maximum allowed size</Message> <ProposedSize>41945391</ProposedSize> <MaxSizeAllowed>41943040</MaxSizeAllowed> <RequestId>yyy</RequestId> <HostId>xxx</HostId> </Error>
```

Contacted Amazon and they have confirmed that they haven't put any restriction on our bucket.

I am using **ng-file-upload** directive to upload the file. Did anyone had this problem using **ng-file-upload** angular directive while uploading file larger than 40MB.

I have checked **.js** files in above directive and cant see anything checking the size but want to double check if i am missing something.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in the policy signature we were creating and in it, we were giving the max_size as 40MB